Renaming File Geodatabase feature class in QGIS
At QGIS 3.34.6, I am unable to rename feature classes or attribute tables using the Browser Panel.  Here's the procedure that I've tried:

From the Browser Panel, open a File Geodatabase by clicking the expand icon.
Right-click a feature class or attribute table and drop down to Manage
At this point, the only option is Delete.  Normally I would expect a Rename option.

So... How do I rename a File Geodatabase feature class or table?
EDIT:
Using the suggestion by User2856, I get the following error:
virtual: Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS ALTER TABLE "county_boundary" RENAME TO "county_boundary_2": 1 - near "ALTER": syntax errorExecution failed after 0.26 seconds
Here are my steps (GDAL version = 3.8.5):

From the Layers panel, highlight the FGDB feature class to be renamed (in this example, county_boundary)
Processing > Toolbox > Vector general > Execute SQL
Within the tool's SQL data entry box, enter the following: ALTER TABLE "county_boundary" RENAME TO "county_boundary_2"
All other data entry boxes were left empty

I don't understand the error.  Any thoughts?

It doesn't appear that you can yet. With the GUI that is.
However, if your GDAL version is >= 3.6 (when write/create was added to the OpenFileGDB driver), you can rename with SQL:
Check GDAL version:

In the Browser pane, right-click the feature class and select "Execute SQL".

Use the following SQL syntax ALTER TABLE "oldname" RENAME TO "newname":

Result:

Or you can use the commandline GDAL ogrinfo utility with the same SQL:
ogrinfo input.gdb -sql "ALTER TABLE oldname RENAME TO newname"


Please see my OP edits.  Any help is appreciated!

@StuSmith the method you mention won't work. See my edit and use the Browser pane to rename.

Ah yes!  The sql is done from the Browser panel, not the Layer panel.  Presto!
